# Android app crashes when made some changes in database

Tags: android

I have developed an android app which consists of database.When i install it on mobile it works fine for first time. when i do some changes in database and install it again without uninstalling the previously installed version, it crashes.

Note:I don't want to uninstall my previous version because i want to retain previously stored data

Any suggestions friends?

Comment: i think when you create or change ant column name get crashes,so uninstall app and install new app

Comment: I don't want to loose my previous data.

Answer (score 3):

Increase your database version number by 1 when you change database structure. (i.e adding new column, removing existed column, changing datatype of column, changing column name etc...).

And put below two lines inside onUpgrade() method of your db helper class.

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS your_table_name_goes_here");
onCreate(db);
```

Everytime it checks the database current version number. If it finds any mismatch between current database version and earlier version  then it simply executes onUpgrade() method to upgrade database. So, we drop all our table(s) and create a new table(s) again.
So now you can add/remove 'n' number of columns while working with db. What all you have to do is just increase the version number by 1 and execute when you change db structure.

Comment: By doing this i will loose my previously store data.isn't it?

Comment: Yes. You will loose previous data. I don't think loosing the previous data while developing the app is a big problem.

Comment: Actually my app is ready to launch..after launching if i need to change my database then its a problem

Comment: Then you should add more logic to the onUpgrade function to migrate the existing data to the new database, that way you won't lose it.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a database you will probably use one if these contructors:

```
public TimePointsSQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                           CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, dbName, factory, dbVersion);
}

private TimePointsSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
}
```

As you can see, there is a variable `dbVersion`, this is the one where you indicate the version of the database to avoid the problem you are having. As a suggestion use a final static int variable to old the version/number of your database so you can change it easily. 
E.g.:

```
public final static int dbVersion = 1;
```

Then you should overrite `onUpgrade(...)` and/or `onDowngrade(...)` in order to apply the changes to your current app and data.

The simplest and fastest way to do it is the one @SANTHOSH mentioned, just drop all the tables and create them again:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS your_table_name");
onCreate(db);
```

beware that with this solution **you will lose your current data** saved in your database. You should add more logic to `onUpgrade` and `onDowngrade` to migrate the data from one version of the database to the other if you want to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

If you made changes such as adding a column to it you need to either do a full uninstall or upgrade the database version.

Either way you will lose all data in the table unless you make a backup of the data first by making a temp database to store it in

Comment: can you please tell me how to increase database version?

Comment: Actually i am not creating database through code.I am just connecting to db which i've created using Sqlite browser. And connecting in code using                                          db =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

String selectQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_TRIP ;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);